# How to set the android datepicker to spinner (not calendar) mode in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When selecting the datepicker control in Xamarin Forms on an android device the Calendar Mode view of the datepicker is shown. How can I change it to show the Spinner Mode?

The only sample I found was to update my styles.xml

Here is what I have, which is not working

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme.Base"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the Resources/values/styles.xml that worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
    <style name="cust_tabViewStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_blue_500</item> 
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then set the theme in the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml by modifying the application node to this

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AppCompat, try this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/style_date_picker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="style_date_picker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you create DatePicker Style in Style.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/style_date_picker</item>
  </style>
  <style name="style_date_picker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>
```

Then You are calling package named `datePickerDialogTheme` for `AppCompatDialogStyle`

It was like

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).