# Xamarin Forms - How to change the shape of the datepicker to a carousel

Tags: xamarin, datepicker

How can I change the shape of the generic Datepicker in xamarin forms to a carousel shape?

[image]

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513868/how-to-set-the-android-datepicker-to-spinner-not-calendar-mode-in-xamarin-form

Comment: @AFORERO Any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing Resources/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

 <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
 </style>
 <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
 <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
   <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
   <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
   <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
   <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
   <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
   <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>    

  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.picker</item>
 
 </style>

 <style name="Theme.picker" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
   <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
  <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
 </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using the plugin [Acr.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)

```
UserDialogs.Instance.DatePrompt(new DatePromptConfig
        {
            Title = "Hello",
            AndroidStyleId = 2
        });
```

[image]